# HTML Button Works Intermittently

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, button, razor, bootstrap-4

So basically as the title says. The button works intermittently. Sometimes it actually hits my code and sometimes it just sits there and does nothing like a dead fish. When it's bugging out like this, it does not hit my breakpoint in VS. I do have to refresh it and it works again.

**Here is my HTML -**

```
  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Home"))
        {
            <div class="contain">

                <form>
                  *insert a bunch of form fields here, I don't think this is relevant, 
                  but if you need to see it, leave a comment*

                   <div class="row centered">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Create Activity</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
      }
}
```

I am not going to post the model because it isn't even hitting the breakpoint I have when you click the button. This is all client-side.

Any ideas? Thank you

EDIT: See @HereticMonkey 's comment. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: how does it even working sometimes? you have no functions call onclick or something.

Comment: What do your browser's dev tools say is happening?  Is the form posting?  Are you getting an error response?

Comment: Note that you have `Html.BeginForm`, which renders a `<form>` element, **and** a `<form>` element. Nested `<form>` elements are invalid in HTML.

Comment: Heretic, hmmm that could be the issue. Let me do some testing. And NaSir, I don't need any functions attached to the button if it is nested in the ``@Html.BeginForm``

Comment: Yep @HereticMonkey that was the issue. Thank you. I guess it was kind of obvious that ``Html.BeginForm`` was like a ``<form></form>``tag, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you have to watch out for is the HTML Helpers that are included in ASP.NET MVC. They help, but are not always explicit in how they help. In this case `Html.BeginForm` renders a `<form>` element for you, so you don't need another one later on.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Home")) { }
```

ends up rendering something like:

```
<form action="/Home/Form"></form>
```

Nested `form` elements are invalid HTML, which causes weird things to happen in browsers.